# Error in backpropgation

Tags: neural-networks

In learning parameters of multilayered neural network by back-propagation, 
is the loss function quantifying scalar or vector(squared-error of input vector) difference between current hypothesis and truth(parameter) for a set of instances, as long as the network is intended to solve the problem of classification?

Comment: By scalar I mean the output of a network with given hypothesis(weight vectors of each neuron). The reason for asking this is that Perceptron started as a linear discriminant where scalar output of a linear function is used for identifying if an instance is positive example of a class. Then shouldn't the loss function of a multilayered neural network quantify the error(distance) between expected scalar and the output scalar value of a network determined by a current hypothesis?

Comment: But in Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation, in Algorithm section, it says "y1, y2 vectors in R(n)" not scalar...

Comment: I would like to respond but I really have no idea what are you asking about. Could you rephrase the question to make it more clear? Possibly also include what you have written in comments? Try be as clear as possible to state what is it that you would like to know. (Good questions get good answers, bad questions... you know).

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for not being clear. If you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation, in section "Algorithm" under Optimization, there is a line saying .... y1, y2 vectors in R(dimension)....

Comment: How can y(output, dependent variable) be vector when a network of linear models is used for classification? I know there is multivariate analysis where response variable can be vector. But in the context of linear discriminant...shouldn't the error be difference in scalar, not in vector?

Comment: Do I make myself clearer a bit?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking if loss function is quantifying a vector. It is better to put a bit formally.

At the output layer, the loss function is a $R^c\rightarrow R$ mapping, where $c$ is the number of classes. For multiclassification, the target in your data need to be one-hot-coded to a vector of length $c$.  For binary classification, if standard logistic regression is used, then $c=1$, if a softmax layer is used, then $c=2$.

The mapping is basically to sum up (or average) the errors for all classes for all data examples. For each data example, you will have this
$$Loss = \sum_{i=1}^c Error^i$$
$$ Error^i=f(y_i, \hat y_i(x, w))$$
$y_i$ is the $i$th element in the one-hot coding vector, and $\hat y_i$ is its estimate by the neural network, $f(\cdot)$ can be squared error or something else.

My answer for your question is yes, the loss function is just summing up a vector of errors for all classes.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating... But there is still a fracture in my concept. After digging some chapters by Haykin and Bishop, let me finish this stupid question.

Comment: Now I've figured it out. For either binary or multi-class problem, there are output node(s) whose dimension can be vector generated by each sign function where sigmoid-like function may output real-value or step function may output either 0 or 1. Then the error can be sum of distances between vectors(network output label and data label) for each instances in the training data.... right? Then, data has always one-hot coding vector but hypothesis may output non-sparse vector when using soft-max activation function.

Answer (score 1):

The loss function calculates the difference between an output vector (that can have a single dimension, in which case it is a scalar), and the expected output vector (again, it can have a single dimension).

---

EDIT :
Vector here means an ordered list of scalars. (Furthermore, there is dependence between those scalars in the multiclass case, if they represent a probability : their sum is 1).

The neural network doesn't do dot products, it does matrix multiplication, between the input (vector, aka N*1 matrix) and a weight matrix.

---

Supplementary note :

For classification, the output of typical networks is a multi dimensional vector representing the probability of each class (as predicted by the network, generally indicating the confidence of the network in its prediction). The loss function used in such cases is typically cross entropy, not euclidian distance.

There are other techniques (changing the representation of the output and/or the loss function), but this is the more standard approach.

Comment: Vector with a single dimension is confusion to me. And also, for multiple class problem, can the k output nodes for k-classes be called a vector? Aren't they just a set of non-interdependent scalar value representing, as you says, probability of the input vector being generated by each class?

Comment: I've always thought that vector starts with at least two dimension...even in the abstract vector space...if a response variable is a single dimension, isn't that a resultant scalar value which can't now be called a vector with single dimension...since it is a projection onto single dimension....

Comment: by dot product of two vectors(w, x).

Comment: Answered those points in the edit. You might want to edit your question, or create new questions, so that people can see them more easily than in a comment chain

Comment: Oh I made a mistake by saying non-interdependent...you're right.